# Fullcalendar timeGridWeek and timeGridDay not loading correctly

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

For my calendar, I'm trying to use the timeGridWeek and timeGridDay views. Instead of loading correctly like this: [image]

it loads like this: [image]

My calendar defaultview is dayGridMonth, which works fine. When I click the buttons that change the view to week or day, it doesn't render correctly AND also doesn't let me change the view further with button clicks (essentially I'm stuck in the view I selected).

Here is my code for the calendar element + imports:

```
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import interactionPlugin, { Draggable } from "@fullcalendar/interaction";

          <FullCalendar
            ref={this.calendarRef}
            defaultView="dayGridMonth"
            height={"parent"}
            width={"parent"}
            droppable={true}
            drop={this.handleDrop}
            dateClick={this.handleDateClick}
            eventClick={this.handleEventClick}
            header={{
              left: "prev,next, today",
              center: "title",
              right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay"
            }}
            plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
            editable={true}
            events={this.state.events}
            eventLimit={true}
          />
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are there any errors in your console? If I had to guess you either forgot to install a plugin file, and/or forgot to add one for more CSS files, and/or the plugins are loaded in the wrong order (I don't know for sure if the order of the `import` statements is important, but I would suggest loading the core fullCalendar plugin first, then the dayGrid, then timeGrid and then the react plugin. Interaction's position doesn't seem to matter so much).

Comment: @ADyson When I click week or day, here's the console log: 
    `main.esm.js:1247 Uncaught TypeError: timeGrid.receiveContext is not a function
    at SimpleTimeGrid.render (main.esm.js:1247)
    at SimpleTimeGrid.Component.receiveProps (main.esm.js:3951)
    at TimeGridView.render (main.esm.js:1331)`

there's a bunch of other stuff. I tried reinstalling the timeGrid plugin with npm after seeing this but the problem is still occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it's fixed! it seems to just be wonky rendering on the local side. When I hosted the app on heroku the timeGridWeek and day both rendered fine. It seems to have just been a faulty installation.

Answer (score 1):

make sure all minor versions of core and plugins are the same, like 4.4.2, not one 4.4.2 other 4.4.0